# How to make a shortcut for rebuild and relaunch debug session with eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I use eclipse neon with cdt plugin for embedded development (mainly Cortex-M targets).
Most projects are makefile based. For remote debugging, I use the `Gdb Hardware Debugging` plugin and Segger Jlink (running JlingGdbServer).
Each time I make changes in source code and then want to run them e.g. under debugger control, I have to:

- stop the current debug session
- build the project
- lauch a new debug session

I want to have this 3 steps executed by a single button click (or keyboard shortcut).
Does anybody know how to archive this?

I think, Nxp's LpcXpresso (also eclipse based) have such button.